# C# drop down list selected value not being set to SQL select statement stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a data-bound drop-down list of collegeID values and I want to select one of these values based on a collegeID in an SQL database. I have a stored procedure to select the ID, but the value is not being selected when the page is run.

My SQL stored procedure is as follows:

```
USE [CONNECTION]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [db_owner].[CollegePersonSelectAll]    Script Date: 5/9/2022 10:50:18 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Alexander Johnson
-- Create date: 5/9/2022
-- Description: CollegePersonSelectAll
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [db_owner].[CollegePersonSelectAll]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @personID int,
    @collegeID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT        collegeID
FROM            CollegePerson
WHERE           personID = @personID
END
```

The code in C# is as follows:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        personID = RetrieveID();
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string dbConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONNECTIONSTRING"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConn);
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[CollegePersonSelectAll]", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", personID);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    _updateCollege.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    collegeID = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    this._message.Text = "Error from SQL " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The HTML for the dropdown list is as follows:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="_college" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDataCollege" DataTextField="collegeName" DataValueField="collegeID" Width="157px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" SelectedValue='%#bind("stateAbbrev")%>'>-Please Select-</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

The `_updateCollege.SelectedValue` does not show the value from the database. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Have you read the docs for `ExecuteNonQuery`? It doesn't return the result of your query... You might be interested in `ExecuteScalar`. And your select is returning 2 values, so even when you correct your code, which value do you need?

Comment: And I highly recommend not using [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: As DaleK has suggested, you should almost certainly be calling `ExecuteScalar` and retrieving ONLY the `collegeID`. It doesn't really make sense to retrieve the `personID` given that you already have it. ALWAYS read the documentation, especially when things don't work as expected. If you had done that then you probably wouldn't have even needed to ask this question. Given that the F1 key takes you straight to the documentation for a type or member, there's no excuse not to read it.

Comment: ExecuteScalar doesn't seem to work either, same issue. Should I be putting something in the ExecuteScalar method?

Comment: Your stored procedure `CollegePersonSelectAll` expects 2 parameters, you only pass in one.  Remove `@collegeID` from the parameters and change your code to use `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: I've updated the post again to include HTML and the fixed C# to include ExecuteScalar

Comment: So, now its a debugging session..., which isn't really what this site is intended for. When you debug it, what is the value of `PersonID`, for that value of `PersonID`, when you run the SP in SSMS, what gets returned? And does that value exist in the drop-down-list at the time you try and assign it?

Comment: My problem is still the same. The value is not being selected in the drop-down list. If I try to remove `Convert.ToString()` it tells me `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'.`

Comment: collegeID holds an empty string `""`. I'm trying to answer your questions but you arent' making much sense. I'm trying to give you the information you're asking for. I'm new to this site please be patient.

Comment: OK, so with the value of PersonID which you have in your code, what do you get when you call the SP in SSMS?

Comment: collegeID is still an empty string after the stored procedure is called `""`

Comment: I believe I should be getting an integer from SSMS if that's what you're asking, unless you mean there is a way to check the SP when it is run, then I don't know how to do that. However, I am getting an object. I'm not exactly sure how to access the data in the object with `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: Fix your stored procedure first. Remove `@collegeID` from the input parameter

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@collegeID` from the input parameter and use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.